# Docker-Compose - Give a container an IP on the hosts network and also allow container to container connections and host net connections

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, lan

I have several containers running in a stack controlled by docker-compose.
Amongst these is one running node-red.

The node-red container needs to be able to search the network for a device that is on the hosts network (192.168.1.0/24).

With the default networking the containers can ping and connect to the host network when they know the IP, unfortunately the node-red implementation only scans the local networks, and it only has the docker bridge network (172...) so it only searches there.

I've tried multiple combinations of the docker network setups to try and get the containers to see the 192 network as local. When I am able to get a 192 network address, the containers can not ping other hosts on the external (to the host machine) network.

TLDR: Docker container needs to be able to see other docker containers and also have an IP address on the hosts network and be able to connect to other services on the hosts network.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution that works for me:

In the docker-compose.yml

```
app:
  image: youimage
  network_mode: "host"
```

adding the `network_mode: "host"` was what I needed